# Is there any word for a person who ruins magician's trick?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, pejorative-language

Is there any word for a person who ruins a magician's trick?

I remember that I heard that word, but it's now lost somewhere in my brain. Can someone please help me to remember that word?

Before asking here I asked in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/14452616#14452616), where I got the response that there is no specific word for it. But I still think there must be.

Comment: Debunker is a person who uncovers the nature of tricks to the public, but that could also be counted as spoiling

Comment: I recently got into magic and most professionals I've seen talking about it (on YouTube and in a real, published, book) use the word 'heckler'.

Comment: What about Scientist?

Comment: [*"Illusion, Michael. A trick is something a whore does for money..."*](http://arresteddevelopment.wikia.com/wiki/G.O.B.)

Comment: "Ruins" the trick in what way?  By explaining how it's done (ruining the mystery) or actually disrupting or interfering with the performance itself?

Comment: @NateEldredge I mean revealing the way the trick was done by magician to other fellow audiences.

Comment: [Related](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/4732/word-for-disrespecting-eldest-half-sister-by-referring-to-her-husband-as-girly-g#comment16076_4732).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

How about *a spoiler* or *a heckler*?

Edit: There is also a [Wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exposure_%28magic%29) that says:

> '*exposure* in magic refers to the practice of revealing the secrets of how magic tricks are performed'.

I am not sure how the term '*exposure'* can be used as an agent noun to refer to someone who does the *'exposure'*.

Comment: I think _spoiler_ is a good word, but I also think this answer could be improved by adding a short explanation about **why** it's a good choice (like a reference to [Macmillan Def. #4](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/spoiler), for example).

Comment: +1 sounds good to me but I think that forgotten word was not "spoiler".. still ok.. :) (_I never heard "heckler" though_)

Comment: Mr Green: There is more than one way I could ruin a trick. I could yell out the secret: _"No, that woman hasn't been sawed in half! She has her legs scrunched under her back!"_ Or, I could just yell insults at the magician, without saying anything about how the tricks work: _"Your show is boring! I think Ron Weasley could do better tricks on his first train ride to Hogwarts!"_ In the first case, I'm playing the _spoiler_; in the second, I'm a mere _heckler_. But either one might ruin the show for you and your kids.

Comment: @J.R. I’m not sure the second is actually a valid insult, given the fact that Ron Weasley is, as a matter of fact, a real wizard, and his spell didn’t work (presumably) because Scabbers isn’t a rat, not because he lacks skills. ;-)

Answer (score 15):

A *[Spoil-sport](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/spoilsport)* is somebody who could reveal the secret to a magician's trick, as per your example, but also the type of person who kicks the ball under the bus, tells a four-year-old that Father Christmas is not real (an obvious lie) and who tips-off the teacher about the whoopee cushion beneath his seat. To accuse somebody of being a *spoil-sport* carries a heavy connotation that their undermining of all fun and happiness is deliberate, and that they are probably deriving some kind of depraved pleasure from the act.

Synonyms include *miser*, *party-pooper* and *killjoy*.

Answer (score 15):

When someone reveals a magician's trick it is referred to in the community as "[exposure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exposure_%28magic%29)".

Magician's logically refer to these people as **[exposurists](https://www.google.com/search?q=exposurist&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a&channel=sb#channel=sb&q=magic%20exposurist&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial)**.

Comment: Not eposurers? :)

Answer (score 4):

I like to use the words Heckler and Debunker. Also Saboteur might be the word you're looking for. I am quite fond of the word Heckler though.